# Regular expression to get the text inside parentheses and match a specified word

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get the string inside parentheses but match 'min' or 'mins'. For example, if I have:

```
 - Closing words (3 min.) 
 - Demonstration (Part One)
```

I Only want to get "3 min" not "Part One". Can someone help me? I'm using python

Comment: `(?<=\()3 mins?(?=\.\))` should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\()[^)]*\bmins?\b[^)]
```

You can try something like this.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/Zd4nAs/1

Answer (score 0):

Since the 3 in "3 min" is a digit, you can use:

```
import re

my_str = """
- Closing words (3 min.) 
- Demonstration (Part One)"""


print(re.search(r"\d+\smin", my_str).group(0))
```

Output:

```
3 min
```